# Resize vector and add data at the end

Tags: c++, vector, resize

I currently have a problem by ressizing a vector of doubles, after I sorted the vector. In the program I get some coordinates (xyz) of points of a given .stl File. To reconstruct this model, I store this coordinates in an vector. So first I create the vector matrix:

```
vector<vector<double> > matrix;
int rows = ((2*lss.size()));//numbers of rows the vector need; lss is a vecotr and stores the coordinates; lss can not be used
int column = 3 //x-,y-,z-coordinates

matrix.resize(rows);

for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        matrix[i].resize(column);
}
```

Then I fill it with data and sort the data:

```
int j=0;
for(size_t i = 0;i<lss.size();i++) {
    int k = j+1;

    matrix[j][0]=lss[i].v[0].x;
    matrix[j][1]=lss[i].v[0].y;
    matrix[j][2]=lss[i].v[0].z;
    matrix[k][0]=lss[i].v[1].x;
    matrix[k][1]=lss[i].v[1].y;
    matrix[k][2]=lss[i].v[1].z;

    j=j+2;
}
std::sort(matrix_zeile.begin(), matrix_zeile.end(), compare2);
```

To close the contour of the model the next step would be to increase the vector, so that one point more can be saved and copy the first point to the end of the vector.
So I tried this code:

```
int rows_new = ((2*lss.size())+2);
matrix.resize(rows_new);

for(size_t i=0; i<rows_new; i++) {
    matrix[i].resize(columns);
}

int p = 2*lss.size();
int q = (2*lss.size())+1;

matrix[p][0]=matrix[0][0];
matrix[p][1]=matrix[0][1];
matrix[p][2]=matrix[0][2];
matrix[q][0]=matrix[0][0];
matrix[q][1]=matrix[0][1];
matrix[q][2]=matrix[0][2];
```

And to print the data to a file, I use this code

```
int o=0;

for (size_t i=0; i<(lss.size()+1); i++) {
    int k=o+1;

    x2=xdiff+matrix[o][0];
    y2=ydiff+matrix[o][1];
    z2=zdiff+matrix[o][2];
    a2=xdiff+matrix[k][0];
    b2=ydiff+matrix[k][1];
    c2=zdiff+matrix[k][2];

    fprintf(f, "X=%f, Y=%f, Z=%f \n", x2,y2,z2);
    fprintf(f, "X=%f, Y=%f, Z=%f \n", a2,b2,c2);

    o=o+2;
}
```

My problem here is the it seems, that the resize function add the new stores space at the beginnign of the vector and not at the end, as I need it. So when I print the coordinates the first to point always have zeros in it.

My Question now is: Is there a possible way to resize the vector and add the new storeg space at the end of the vector matrix?

Comment: Maybe the first point *is* zero? Have you checked the vector you copy from?

Comment: And if you check e.g. [this `std::vector::resize` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) you will see that the new elements already *are* appended.

Comment: How about `matrix.push_back(matrix.front())`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I checked the vector I copy from and the first elements aren't zeros. I also used the reference you provide me to write my code, that's why I'm asking here. For me it seemed like my code is doing not the same as the code in the reference.

Comment: You forgot to resize the columns of the 2 new rows you added. So your code has a runtime error. As Joachim Pileborg said, resize works as intended and appends at the end.

Comment: @KarstenKoop: When I delete my code for resizing the vector and try to use the push_back I get an errro message: _Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable_

Comment: @rozina: Sorry I forgot to copy this codeline. I edited my question

Comment: Here is a simplified version of your code that works as intended after the fix. [LINK](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77e6b03d7677442f)

Comment: There is no error in the code you posted. I suggest you create a minimal compilable example (in an online compiler preferably) and post it. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: @rozina : Thanks for your help. The pushback function is working now quit fine. Also thankt to JoachimPileborg and KarstenKoop